# Context-free grammar for specific language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm really stuck with a problem about context-free grammars.

I need to give a cfg for the following language :

```
L = {w | ∃u,v ∈ {a,b}*,∃x∈{c}*,x≠λ : w = uxv ∧ N_a(u)=N_a(v)}
```

λ Stands for the empty word (so x should be of length >= 1)

N_a(u) Stands for the number of a's in u.

I've been stuck with this problem for many hours now.

I know how the words of the language look like. But I can't get it to the CfG.

It would be very nice if someone has some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we need `uxv` such that `u` and `v` are strings of `a`s and `b`s, `x` is a string of `c`s and `u` and `v` have the same number of `a`s?

When you're trying to figure out a grammar for a language, it helps to think of some of the shortest words you can imagine being in the language, and what rules you can use to make bigger words. These shortest strings and rules will become productions in your grammar.

Question: what's the shortest string in this language?
Answer: `c`.

Question: Given a string `x` in the language, how can we get a longer string in the language?
Answer: we can add strings with the same number of `a`s to the front and back of `x`.

These are enough hints to get started. We can start with a rough idea:

```
S := C | ASA
C := c | cC
```

Now, the trick is figuring out productions for A that will give us all strings in the language, but give us only strings in the language. Suppose that the productions for A can produce a strings with differing numbers of `a`s; this would break our grammar, because you'd be able to put fewer `a`s in front than behind, getting a string not in the language. This means that whatever productions for A we add, we should only get strings containing some fixed number of `a`s. Additionally, we want to choose a number of `a`s so that, by putting them in a linear combination, we can get all numbers of `a`s in our final strings, i.e., by appending many As, we should be able to get any number of `a`s. Convince yourself that the only logical choice for a single value for the number of `a`s to be produced by productions for A is one (1). This suggests `A := XaY`, where `X` and `Y` don't produce `a`s.

We must also allow any number of `b`s, in any position, to be in our string. This part is actually easy - we can take `B = (empty) | bB` to get any number of `b`s. Since `A` produces only a single `a`, we can take `A := BaB` as our production, so that `A` generates `b*ab*`. Our grammar is now:

```
S := C | ASA
A := BaB
B := (empty) | bB
C := c | cC
```

The language this accepts is as follows: `(b*ab*)^n c+ (b*ab*)^n` for any nonnegative `n`. Here, `n` is the number of times one applies the rule `S := ASA` in deriving a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super enlightening Answer ! I'll need to study the procedure you've done to get there later because I'm on my phone now. but this looks very promising !